# How can I mirror my phone to Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, phone

I have a Nexus 6 phone. I have a smaller PC with Ubuntu 15.04 connected to my TV. How can I stream my phones screen to the Ubuntu machine, with Airplay like behavior? My phone has Chromecast client built in, but Miracast is not supported afaik. I dont have a Chromecast stick. 
Is there a Chromecast/similar server available on Ubuntu?